# Best practice when substring is missing from string

Tags: python, string, substring

I'm extracting data from an API and one of the fields is a string from which i want to extract multiple substrings(7 ideally). To get those substring I'm using the index() method.

```
string = r"""[Summary]
Reason: Not enough information
Improvements_Done: None
Improvements_Planned: Documentation
References_Improvements_Done: None
References_Improvements_Done: None
References_Improvements_Planned: www.link1.com
References_Improvements_Planned: www.link2.com
 *** DEFAULT.....""".replace("\n", "\r\n")

Ex: imp_done_start = string.index('Improvements Done: ') + len('Improvements Done: ')
    imp_done_end = string.index('Improvements_Planned')
    imp_done = string[imp_done_start:imp_done_end]
```

There could be cases when one or more of these substrings(Reason ,Improvements_Done, Improvements_Planned etc) could be missing from the string.
For example if "Improvements_Planned" is missing then i can't get the value for imp_done.

What is the best practice to handle these kind of cases?

Comment: why not regex: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re

Comment: I have always used regex for these applications. If you have never worked with regular expressions, it may take some time to get comfortable with it. But IMO it is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice depends largely on the format. However, in most cases, you can adopt a *flexible* approach and convert to an easier to parse/analyze intermediate representation:

```
import re

def parse(s: str) -> dict[str, str]:
    d = {}
    lines = s.splitlines()

    for line in lines[1:-1]:
        pattern = r"^(.*)?: (.*)$"
        m = re.match(pattern, line)
        if m is None:
            continue
        d[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)

    return d
```

Usage:

```
>>> parse(string)
{'Improvements_Done': 'None',
 'Improvements_Planned': 'Documentation',
 'Reason': 'Not enough information',
 'References_Improvements_Done': 'None',
 'References_Improvements_Planned': 'www.link2.com'}
```

Now further analyse the result with any further rules required.